# How to change value at a memory address?

Tags: assembly

I am solving Memory Corruption CTF (msp430 assembly)

How can I put the value 0x3c4f inside address 0x439c (r15 from Register state)? When cmp instruction executes, we want the value at memory address 0x439c to be equal to 0x3c4f.

[image]

One thing to note is cmp instruction will compare 2 bytes

.W : The suffix .W or **no suffix** at the
instruction memonic will result in
a word operation

I appreciate your help!

Should I put 3 in 0x439c, c in 0x439d, 4 in 0x439e and f in 0x439f?

Comment: I'd like to help you answer your question, but I'm not sure I understand the full scope of your situation. What is Micro Corruption?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It's actually Memory corruption CTF. Sorry for my mistake. Just edited it.